# How to disable key navigation in a ListBox but keep detect the key press events?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, keypress, routed-events

I'm trying to disable the key navigation in a `ListBox`. I can do it successfully with this code below :

```
private void listClips_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

but I wanna add a keyboard shortcut for my program. It's not working when I set  `e.Handled = true`.

```
private void listClips_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Key Pressed " + e.Key);
}
```

How can I keep both of them functional?

Comment: What you want is the solution from this Thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918642/equivalent-to-a-keypreview-property-in-wpf

Comment: Thanks but i couldn't make it work. It's keeping navigate on listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you move your logic to the `PreviewKeyDown` handler?

```
private void listClips_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //custom logic...
    MessageBox.Show("Key Pressed " + e.Key);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Handle any shortcuts you want and always set the `Handled` property to `true` afterwards.